# Unity3d: Unable to include LibSodium libraries

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, libsodium

I am working on a unity project and want to use Sodium for cryptography (public key sealed box). The problem is, when I install any library (and I've tried many), the library appears in the assembly references section for a few seconds and then disappears. Consequently, I have been unable to use it.

The error looks like this:

> The type or namespace name 'NSec' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Also I've used many different libraries but they just don't work.

Comment: Maybe you need this? https://github.com/ektrah/nsec

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this did not work. But I got it to work after getting a few hours of sleep. I will explain.

Comment: Please consider adding an answer rather than editing your original post.

Comment: Oh, OK will do now.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Turns out I am too much of an IDIOT to have not tried it in the first place. How it worked:

> The NuGet PM gets the packages in the project's root/Packages directory. All I had to do was move the package from that dir to a dir inside the Assets dir (/Assets/Plugins).